# How do I connect my windows 10 PC to my Raspberry Pi 3 using Wifi Direct?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct

My Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspian) is a robot and needs to drive around. 
At home, I control it using Windows 10/Putty over SSH. However, in 2 weeks I will be demonstrating it in a place where I have no control over the wifi connection, and I don't want to be reliant on a potentially heavily firewalled network.

I read that Wifi Direct would allow me to SSH into my Raspi (and thus control it) using my Windows 10 laptop, without using an existing wifi network. My laptop supports Wifi Direct. However, all tutorials appear to be concerned with connecting the Raspi with an Android app, and not windows 10/Putty.

How do I connect my windows 10 laptop to my Raspi using a Wifi Direct connection?

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is use a spare router as a switch to create a local wireless network, and connect both my laptop and my pi to it. I could hence establish a  ssh connection.